# Fortinet 3600C historical bandwidth data retrieval

Tags: performance, firewall, bandwidth

I'm using fortinet 3600C along with fortianalyzer 400E. I am trying to retrieve the bandwidth usage from historical data for the past one year. I'm able to visualize from the fortinet dashboard a historical bandwidth data for one week.  Im using fortianalyzer version 6.2.9. Any suggestions please to overcome the issue?

Thanks in Advance!!!

I tried to retrive through existing templates on fortianalyzer in which i was able to fetch only the total data exchanged in a day details. Need support to get the bandwidth variation throughout the day for past one year.